# 400 Bad Request when putting a list of object through @RequestBody

Tags: json, spring-boot, http-status-code-400

I am making an API for the frontlline to return me a list of courses by JSON. However, whatever I tried, I get the below error. Anyone can help?

```
  "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "trace": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.vtxlab.course.entity.Courses` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.vtxlab.course.entity.Courses` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:391)\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:343)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.
```

Here is my API.

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/courses")
  public List<Courses> saveAll(@RequestBody List<Courses> courses) {
    return courseService.saveAll(courses);
```

JSON testing:

```
[
    
{
    "courseName": "DATAANALYSES",
    "courseFee":   "20000.00",
    "startDate": "2022-12-01"
},
{
    "courseName": "CSS",
    "courseFee":   "30000.00",
    "startDate": "2022-12-01"
}
]
```

Comment: Please share the courses class.

Comment: Your API saves the list of courses and returns the list that you sent and saved. The method is POST. In your question you didn't provide the class Courses and didn't specify how you invoked your API so, your question is not complete